# How many #8 digits can you build?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different 8-digit numbers can be formed using two 1s, two 2s, two 3s, and two 4s such that no two
>   adjacent digits are the same?

So we have $0 -> 9 = 10$ options for the digits but with the constraints we have something different.

Cases:

$1$ _ _

$2$ _ _

$3$ _ _

$4$ _ _

We can do recursion in the form $A(N), B(N),.. D(N)$ as to how many sequences can be built from the $1, 2, .. 4$ for $N$ letters.

We have $T(n) = A(N-1) + B(N-1) + C(N-1) + D(N-1)$

We are after $T(8)$. We have that for instance $A(n-1) = B(n-2) + C(n-2) + D(n-2) = [A(n-3) + C(N-3) + D(n-3)] + [A(n-3) + B(n-3) + D(n-3)] + [A(n-3) + B(n-3) + C(n-3)] = 3A(n-3) + 2B(n-3) + 2C(n-3) + 2D(n-3)$. 
But this gets long fast.

Comment: The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the total number of sequences, which is $\frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $11$, which is $\frac{7!}{1!2!2!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $22$, which is $\frac{7!}{1!2!2!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $33$, which is $\frac{7!}{1!2!2!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $44$, which is $\frac{7!}{1!2!2!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $11$ and $22$, which is $\frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $11$ and $33$, which is $\frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $11$ and $44$, which is $\frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $22$ and $33$, which is $\frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $22$ and $44$, which is $\frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $33$ and $44$, which is $\frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $11$ and $22$ and $33$, which is $\frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $11$ and $22$ and $44$, which is $\frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $11$ and $33$ and $44$, which is $\frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}$
- Exclude the number of sequences containing $22$ and $33$ and $44$, which is $\frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}$
- Include the number of sequences containing $11$ and $22$ and $33$ and $44$, which is $\frac{4!}{1!1!1!1!}$

---

Hence the number of such sequences is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{4}(-1)^n\cdot\binom4n\cdot\frac{(8-n)!}{(1!)^n(2!)^{4-n}}=864$.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

There are $\frac{8!}{2^4}$ 8-digits numbers that can be formed using two 1s, two 2s, two 3s, and two 4s.

i) How many of these 8-digits numbers have two adjacent 1s? 
There are $7\cdot \frac{6!}{2^3}$ such numbers.

ii) How many of these 8-digits numbers have two adjacent 1s and two adjacent 2s in this order? There are
$15\cdot \frac{4!}{2^2}$ such numbers.

iii) How many of these 8-digits numbers have two adjacent 1s, two adjacent 2s and two adjacent 3s in this order? There are
$10\cdot \frac{2!}{2^1}$ such numbers.

iv) How many of these 8-digits numbers have two adjacent 1s, two adjacent 2s, two adjacent 3s and two adjacent 4s in this order? They is only $1$ such number.

Hence the final result is (why?):
$$\frac{8!}{2^4}-4\cdot7\cdot \frac{6!}{2^3}
+(4\cdot 3)\cdot 15\cdot \frac{4!}{2^2}
-(4\cdot 3\cdot 2)\cdot 10\cdot \frac{2!}{2^1}
+(4!)\cdot 1\cdot \frac{0!}{2^0}=864.$$